# How to solve Google Sceneform Tools ​(Beta) Plugin installation error in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I want to use Google ARCore in my app. So I want to install Google Sceneform Tools plugin. But after installation and restart the IDE I see this notification:

"Plugin Error: Plugin "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)."

[Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSLkG.png)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Google sceneform is deprecated.

Comment: So can I convert a .obj file to .sfa file without this plugin?

Comment: Now you can work with obj or fbx only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, Sceneform is now **deprecated**, but...
You can deal with it by three ways:

1. Installing older version of Android Studio (3.5.2 or lower) and then Sceneform plugin should work normally.
2. Using [this GitHub repo.](https://github.com/gdamoreira/google-ar-asset-converter) It is somehow based on Sceneform plugin but works externally. With basic knowledge of cmd/bash it allowes you to convert `.obj` files to `.sfa` and `.sfb` files. But in my case it could not properly convert `.fbx` animated 3D models.
3. Following guide in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/create-renderables#load_3d_models_at_runtime) you should be able to load `.glb` and `.gltf` at runtime without any conversion.

I hope this will help to someone ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am using Sceneform 1.16.0 and it works fine after upgrading that to Androidx. But it don't support sfa or sfb files, only glb files. Here's an article I wrote about a simple AR app, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-simple-augmented-reality-android-app/

Answer (score 0):

As sceneform is deprecated .sfa and .sfb models are not supported . however, you can use gltf and glb models